# Extjs. How to arrange data from left to right in the grid. Single column headings

Tags: extjs, extjs6

Please tell me. How to arrange data from left to right in the grid. Single column headings.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csNSv.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `Ext.grid.header.Container` states only top or bottoms are available.

If you want to archive this you have to use a `layout: 'hbox'` and a template pushing each item into view.