# Have an extjs grid column vertical

Tags: extjs

I've seen multiple posts of how to have a grid column headers display text vertically, but I'm looking for how to have the columns themselves be rows. I want to be able to drag/drop rows, but the plugin that I've tried to use doesn't want to seem to work. The section that I'm using this for just has a name, and a value, as it was originally a property grid, and I want a way to rotate the grid 90 degrees, so I can drag the columns instead of trying to drag the rows.

Note: I'm not using the most recent version of EXT js, this is a work project, so I can't really update easily.

Comment: Did you see this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70194520/extjs-how-to-arrange-data-from-left-to-right-in-the-grid-single-column-heading

Comment: I did not, thank you for the information.